# How often do localized versions of movies localize shots?

Tags: production, distribution, translation, the-neverending-story

When a movie is released internationally, it is not unbeknown to localize credits and title sequences (on top of the must-dos — localizing audio and, often, subtitles).

But [*The NeverEnding Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_NeverEnding_Story_(film)) takes it to the next level. In the German version (which, if I am not mistaken, was actually the original one — although the actors' lips speak English), not only the title sequence and the credits are different, but so are a few actual shots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have never seen anything like that in any other movie.

How (un)common is it?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144988/discussion-on-question-by-greendrake-how-often-do-localized-versions-of-movies-l); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Some examples that would require pictures to deserve the answer, the broccoli pizza in inside out, CptAmerica Bucket list, Shaun the sheep, I'm pretty sure some things were localized in zootopia too, but not certain. It's way more frequent in kid movies and in animation.